# Even if the user is logged in, I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem:
I want a logged in user to be able to use my `getRealtimeUsers` function. But I get the following error: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Below you will find the code. Some explanations:
On the React side, I created a firebase, registered a `getRealtimeUsers` function there, and tried to use it.

firebase.js file

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

A function that uses the firebase I created:

```
import firebase from '../../firebase';

export const getRealtimeUsers = () => {

    return async () => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const unsubscribe = db.collection("users")
        return unsubscribe;
    }
}
```

Testing of the function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getRealtimeUsers } from '../redux/actions/chatActions';

import firebase from '../firebase';
let unsubscribe;

class chat extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        unsubscribe = this.props.getRealtimeUsers()
            .then(unsubscribe => {
                return unsubscribe;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        return () => {
            unsubscribe.then(f => f()).catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }

    render() {

        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
        return (

                <div>
                    check if works
                </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        getRealtimeUsers
    }
);
```

Here I let the user do the login
login.js action

```
export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post('/login', userData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};
```

The login is done on the nodejs side, which is also where I set it to firebase:

```
const config =  {
    apiKey: "WqcVU",
    authDomain: "c468.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "c468",
    storageBucket: "c468.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "087",
    appId: "1:087:web:c912",
    measurementId: "G-SQX1"
  };
  ;

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Log user in
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    };
    
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        return data.user.getIdToken();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
app.post('/login', login);
```

the rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want only a logged in user to use the `getRealtimeUsers` function, but even if the user is logged in it doesnt work. That's my problem.

I do not know at all how to solve it

Comment: You initialize your firebase app twice, with possibly different configuration: `firebase.initializeApp(config);` Why? May be you login to one app, and make your request to another

Comment: this is exactly the same firebase

Comment: Is it the same instance though? If you re-initialize before calling `getRealtimeUsers`, you may loose the authentication state. Are you able to make any other request to firebase after login?

Comment: How can you use the same instance? It shows I am not authenticated , But I do

Comment: In your login file, use `import firebase from '../../firebase';` and do not initialize firebase.

Comment: Explain to me again please. One time the firebase is initialized in react, and the second time it is initialized in nodejs

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast, I didn't realize the last piece of code was from nodejs. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I hope those firebase configs you put are not real, you shouldn't share that kind of info

Comment: No they are for illustration only, thanks for the attention!

Comment: What does the function `setAuthorizationHeader` do?

Comment: As @jperl metioned what `setAuthorizationHeader` do? Basically this error occur becauase your authrization header is not set when calling the firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is really problematic, the only way to do security in rules is to access your correntUser or auth. Because you connect through the nodejs, you only return json object and there will be no access to these objects.

For you to have access to these objects what you need to do is connect once more, in react itself, with the same firebase and that's how you enjoy all the worlds that firebase has to offer.

When you log in again, the user does not need to know about it, since when you log in you will reset the password, and choose a random password, it will solve all your problems.

I think this is the most likely solution, but it is not for production

Please update me.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're not authenticating directly from the client? The thing is you have to pass in some way the authenticated state from the server to the front...

You have signed in with firebase on your server but you did not sign in with firebase on the front end. Or maybe you did in `setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);` but I'd be curious to know how you did that. It would have been interesting to be able to authenticate with nodejs and then send the tokenId which has been generated, that is `data.user.getIdToken()`, to the client which the client would then pass to `firebase.auth().signInWithToken(token)` but this is not possible. If you want to know more about it, I invite you to read this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2291) (a feature request).

The way to solve this problem is to use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

> Firebase gives you complete control over authentication by allowing you to authenticate users or devices using secure JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). You generate these tokens on your server, pass them back to a client device, and then use them to authenticate via the signInWithCustomToken() method.
>
> To achieve this, you must create a server endpoint that accepts sign-in credentials—such as a username and password—and, if the credentials are valid, returns a custom JWT. The custom JWT returned from your server can then be used by a client device to authenticate with Firebase (iOS, Android, web). Once authenticated, this identity will be used when accessing other Firebase services, such as the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Storage. Furthermore, the contents of the JWT will be available in the auth object in your Realtime Database Rules and the request.auth object in your Cloud Storage Security Rules.

Here are the steps:

1. First, you will add the SDK to your server:

```
yarn add firebase-admin --save
```

and import it

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
```

2. Go over to your Project settings under the "Service accounts" tab.

[image]

and click on "Generate a new private key"

[image]

3. a file has been downloaded and saved on your machine. From there, you will either import the file and initialize `admin` like this:

```
var serviceAccount = require("/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

or better yet, in the console

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"
```

and in your file

```
const credential = admin.credential.applicationDefault() // this will automatically find your env variable
admin.initializeApp({
    credential
})
```

Note: don't forget to set the proper permissions to the private key file with chmod (I had to).

4. nodejs

```
firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data) => {
            admin
            .auth()
            .createCustomToken(data.user.uid)
            .then((customToken) => {
                console.log('customToken', customToken)
                // send token back to client here
                res.send(customToken)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

and then on the client:

```
// get the token and then
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        var user = userCredential.user;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
```

---

Another solution would be not using firebase on the client at all and use the backend as some sort of proxy between firebase and the client. The client would make a request to the backend which in turn would interrogate firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I do not know how to use the solution you gave me, because I already have a lot of things built on the firebase I have, and making a change with customToken, could be disrupting everything I have so far.

Comment: Another solution would be to send requests to your server that will do the actual request for the client to firebase. Or you sign in a second time with the email and the password on the front end.

Comment: Although to be honest with you, I don't see how that could disrupt anything. Custom Token seems to be exactly what you're looking for. I just read the docs. This is what they say: 

Firebase gives you complete control over authentication by allowing you to authenticate users or devices using secure JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). You generate these tokens on your server, pass them back to a client device, and then use them to authenticate via the signInWithCustomToken() method.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to do what you told me, and I will update you.

Comment: @dustyeav could I please have an update? Have you been able to sort it out? If so, how? If you found a way, I'll be interesting to know how, thank you. Also, don't forget to post it here.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to solve the problem, what I did was, I made an option to login, once again to firebase but from react.
And so I was able to get the access to auth I wanted.
I connected synchronously, 2 times, once in nodejs, and once more in react.
And that actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, faced same problem with rule's.

please give a try, change your rue and check whether its working or not

[image]